# How to store JSON recieved from REST api service into a variable using Javascript

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to get a JSON from 
https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key=DEMO_KEY&query=ketchup 
and do something with it by storing it into a variable. I used Node and Express in my work. Can anyone please tell me how to.
Very much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your code? Please review this question on how to do a minimum reproducible example, for a better experience to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: you can use, axios or got or SuperAgent or Request or HTTP-the Standard Library in nodejs

Answer (score 1):

I asume that your server is working and fetching data correctly.
Then you can use something like that:

```
async function getData() {
  return fetch('https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key=DEMO_KEY&query=ketchup')
    .then(response => response.json())
}

getData()
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Like **zinkn** say [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62368482/is-it-possible-to-use-async-without-await-in-js)